# GPO setting about "Advanced System Settings" Permission on Windows Server

Tags: windows-10, active-directory

How can I disable the permission control on "Advanced System Settings" in GPO.

I have try all of the account including Administrator but still can't enter in "Advanced System Settings".

Server: Windows Server 2016

Client: Windows 10

Comment: Are you an Administrator on the AD domain itself?

Comment: Yeap! I can login the AD server and configuring it.
The problem is I have no idea how to disable the permission control on  "Advanced System Settings".

Comment: You said you can't enter the `Advanced System Settings`, which implies the policy is enabled not disabled, otherwise you would be able to access it.  Just because you can log into the AD server does not mean you have Administrator access on the domain itself (I can log into my AD server as a previliaged and/or non-previliaged user).

Comment: I can log into my AD server with domain administrator account.

Comment: @Kevin are you wanting to make a GPO that disables end users (& their machines [Win10 in your example]) from getting INTO `Advanced System Settings` meaning the `System` item in Control Panel (& right-click Win10 start button)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood you. I'll assume you want to make a GPO that disables end users (& their machines [Win10 in your example]) from getting INTO Advanced System Settings meaning the Control Panel 'System' item; which is also accessible from right-click Win10 start button.

- To disable Control Panel entirely, enable this: [User Configuration{\Policies}\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Prohibit access to Control Panel and PC settings](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#4696)
- To disable just 'System' Control Panel item: [User Configuration{\Policies}\Administrative Templates\Control Panel\Hide specified Control Panel items](https://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/#4694)

  - Enable the above, then enter in `Microsoft.System`

If you're wanting to lock this down on a server where end-users have remote access the process might be a little different.